# Adding data to jointable in a loop after adding data to one of the joint models Cakephp2

Tags: cakephp, many-to-many, has-and-belongs-to-many, cakephp-2.x

So im making an online shop where i want to make each purchase have multiple products. I have the tables products, purchases and product_purchases. I want this function to add a row to purchases (that part works), substract the required stock (also works) and add the number of rows needed to product_purchases. The problem is that only the last row gets saved into the join table.

```
public function add($price=null){

        $user_id = $this->Session->read('Auth.User')['id'];
        
        $purchase_in = array();
        $purchase_in['Purchase']['user_id']= $user_id;
        $purchase_in['Purchase']['price']= $price;
        $this->Purchase->save($purchase_in);

        $jointable_in = array();
        $Purchase = array();

        $purchase_id=$this->Purchase->getInsertID();

        $Purchase['id_purchase']= $purchase_id;

        $jointable_in['Purchase']['Purchase']= $Purchase;

        $cart = $this->Session->read('cart');


        foreach ($cart as $product_id) {
            $product = $this->Purchase->Product->findById($product_id);

            $stock = ($product['Product']['stock'])-1;

            $stock_in = array();
            $stock_in['Product']['id']= $product_id;
            $stock_in['Product']['stock']= $stock;
            $this->Purchase->Product->save($stock_in);

            
            $product = array();

            $product['id_product']= $product_id;
            $jointable_in['Product']['Product']= $product;
            
            $this->Product->Purchase->save($jointable_in);
            
        }
        return $this->redirect(array('controller'=>'products','action' => 'cartempty'));

    }
```

Ive tried saving into ProductsPurchase model but doesnt work, ive also tried inputting an array like in [the cookbook](https://book.cakephp.org/2/en/models/saving-your-data.html#saving-related-model-data-habtm) to saveAll and it doesnt save anything, ive also tried to do this $this->Product->Purchase->clear() after each save but it adds empty rows to the purchases table so i dont know what else to try.

Comment: "Making an online shop" sounds like you're creating this from scratch. If so, why are you using v2 which is years out of date now?

Comment: Im studying web apps development and im on the end of my last year, in this year, i need to work 3 months in a business and finish a final web proyect wich we have to do using technologies that werent taught in the course. The business uses cakephp2, so im using it in my proyect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally solved this, i just had to use saveAll() function once.

In my code i tried to save the purchase first and the HABTM table data after that. The main problem was that by doing it that way cake was treating them as separate records.

In the end i included the data from the first save in the array for the second one and saved it outside the loop.

public function add($price=null){
$idusuario = $this->Session->read('Auth.User')['id'];

```
    $jointable_in = array();
    $aux_array = array();

    $Purchase = array();
    $Purchase['user_id']= $idusuario;
    $Purchase['price']= $price;

    $aux_array['Purchase']= $Purchase;

    $products = array();
    $carrito = $this->Session->read('cart');
    $i=0;

    foreach ($carrito as $idproducto) {
        $producto = $this->Purchase->Product->findById($idproducto);
        $stock = ($producto['Product']['stock'])-1;
        $sales = ($producto['Product']['sales'])+1;

        $stock_in = array();
        $stock_in['Product']['id']= $idproducto;
        $stock_in['Product']['stock']= $stock;
        $stock_in['Product']['sales']= $sales;
        //$this->Purchase->Product->save($stock_in);

        $shop = $this->Product->Shop->findById($producto['Product']['shop_id']);
        $shop_in = array();
        $shop_in['Shop']['id']= $shop['Shop']['id'];
        $shop_sales = ($shop['Shop']['sales'])+1;
        $shop_in['Shop']['sales']= $shop_sales;

        //$this->Product->Shop->save($shop_in);


        $products[$i]=$idproducto;
        $i++;
    }

    $aux_array['Purchase']['count']=$i;

    $aux_array['Product']['Product']= $products;
    array_push($jointable_in,$aux_array);

    //exit(debug($jointable_in));

    $this->Purchase->saveAll($jointable_in,array('deep' => true));

    return $this->redirect(array('controller'=>'products','action' => 'cartempty'));
}
```